# How to have scrolling collection of uipageviewcontrollers

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I currently have a UICollectionView that scrolls vertically and this is the perfect layout for my content, however now I need each element in that collection to be a flip through of pages just like the UIPageViewController. I can't seem to figure out how to combine these two types of views. The collectionview cell (if I understand correctly) cannot contain a viewcontroller. What would be an approach to achieve this?

Comment: A collection view cell can contain a view managed by a separate view controller.

Comment: Thanks - that worked. Did not realize it was that simple.